# Shortest path of a graph after modifying its weights.

Tags: graph-theory

Given an undirected G(V,E) with positive weights $$e_1 \leq e_2 \leq \dots \leq e_n $$  and a shortest path P from vertex s to vertex u, is P going to change or is it going to change if we modify the weights to be $$2^{e_1} \leq 2^{e_2} \leq \dots \leq 2^{e_n} $$To be honest I think the path will remain the same in terms of vertices as all edges grow the same and the number of edges of the path does not affect it.To prove it I thought of assuming that the path will change and somehow come to a contradiction using the formula of $$\sum 2^n =2^{n+1} -1$$ but that didn't do the trick so a bit of insight would be really useful.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No.

- Path A:  $1$, $4$
- Path B:  $2$, $2$, $2$

[image]